# Is there a list of Chemical Weapon Industry Facilities/Funders?

Tags: usa

This question was recently asked on NICAR and got crickets:

Can anybody point me in the right direction for data on state or regional presence (or lack) of chemical weapons industry facilities/funders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_and_weapons_of_mass_destruction#Chemical_weapons_disposal):
"the United States had destroyed 89.75% of the original stockpile of nearly 31,100 metric tons (30,609 long tons) of nerve and mustard agents declared in 1997."

"The primary remaining chemical weapon storage facilities in the U.S. are Pueblo Chemical Depot in Colorado and Blue Grass Army Depot in Kentucky.[28] These two facilities hold 10.25% of the U.S. 1997 declared stockpile."

Another good place to start would be the EPA: http://www.epa.gov/envirofw/geo_data.html

You can sort out the type of regulated sites you are looking for and extrapolate which are likely candidates.

[Here is a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biosafety_level#List_of_BSL-4_facilities) of Biosafety Level 4 Facilities which are those facilities designed for work with extremely dangerous pathogens.